# How do Phoenix templates manage state?

Tags: model-view-controller, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm working on a card game in Elixir where the state of the game is managed by a GenServer. When the user navigates to "games/new" I've added a line in the GameController#new action to start the GenServer and return the initialized state. Then I can pass this state into the template by the call to render.

```
def new(conn, _params) do
    changeset =
      conn.assigns[:current_user]
      |> Ecto.build_assoc(:games)
      |> GamePlay.change_game()

      War.GamePlay.Game.start_game()

      %War.GamePlay.Game{user_cards: user_hand, computer_cards: comp_hand, status: status} =
        Server.read(War.GamePlay.Server)
    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset, user_hand: user_hand, comp_hand: comp_hand, status: status)
  end
```

In my template, I can use these variables to grab the state like so,

```
<h4>  Game Status:  <%= @status %> </h4>
```

and it will return "in progress".

I don't want the user to navigate away from the page but how would I call my GenServer from the view? For example, in the game of war, the user will need to click "next card", how is this tied to the GenServer so that the button calls that function? How do I pass the current state to the template?

Answer (score 2):

Once the view has been rendered, you can no longer just call your `GenServer`. In this case, you will probably want to look into using [channels](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/channels.html). This would allow you to continue calling your `GenServer` upon some action that happens on the client.

Comment: Once the view is rendered is there any way to partially refresh it. For example, I only want to refresh the elements that have changed like rails turbolinks. I suppose I could use ajax but you're suggesting making the calls from a lobby_channel.ex or something like that?

Comment: You could use turbolinks (which is just ajax calls) within Phoenix. It isn't specific to rails. But yes, you will have the logic within the channel.

Comment: <advertisement> This looks like a case for Drab (https://tg.pl/drab). </advertisement>